# Prove that $L = \{0^n1^m \mid n ≥ 10, m ≤ 50\}$ is regular and that any subset of it is regular

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, regular-expressions, finite-automata

Question:
**Let L = {0<sup>n</sup>1<sup>m</sup>, n ≥ 10 m ≤ 50}. Prove that this is a regular language and that any subset of it is also regular.**

**Answer or approach:** 0 is regular, 1 is regular since any symbol in ∑ is regular. Then 1<sup>n</sup>, n≥10 is regular, because of concatenation of regular languages. Similar argument for 1<sup>m</sup>. Then 1<sup>n</sup>1<sup>m</sup> is regular because concatenation of regular languages is regular.

Not sure about the subset begin regular part...

Is my answer/approach a good place to start, or am I going the wrong way?

Should I design a NFA/DFA for it instead? I think doing so would be harder....

any hints or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: It is _not true_ that any subset of $L$ is regular. For example, $\{0^{10+p}\mid p\text{ is prime}\}$ is a subset of $L$ but is not regular.

Comment: You have typos in your argument: you should be talking about $0^n$ not $1^n$. Re subsets: the last claim is very false. There are many examples of subsets of $L$ that are not regular. @HenningMakholm showed one. Here's another:  $\{0^n\mid n\in K\}$, where $K$ is an undecidable set of integers, such as the indexes of programs that terminate when run on themselves as input (the halting problem). // Unless it's supposed to be $n\le 10$, in which case $L$ and any subset of it are finite, therefore regular (why?)

Comment: More generally, any infinite language (as in your case) has uncountably many different subsets, while there are only countably many regular languages, so the second part of the exercise holds for **no** infinite language at all.